# fail recover JSON in Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Always have same problem with query mobile accessing to dynamic data.
I use jquery and jquerymobile

I can see with firebug how JSON is OK, but i try recovered data for can use in list view don't can capture it.

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/lordnigh/LD6YA/9/
if i define function error always is showed  , but i don't know why , the sintaxis of JSON is right.

The output of JSON is this:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function(){    
        var url2 = 'http://www.domain.com',
        mode2 = 'ws.php?TIPO=',
        key2='OK';
function logicaCliente(data){
    console.log(data);
}
    $.ajax({
        url: url2+mode2+key2 ,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            $.each(result, function(i, row) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
            $('#data-list').append('<li><a href="" data-id="' + row.id + '"><h3>' + row.nombre + '</h3><p>' + row.denominacion + '</p></a></li>');
             });
        $('#data-list').listview('refresh');
        },
        error: alert('Error en respuesta'),
        jsonpCallback: 'logicaCliente'
    });         
});


}
```

> [{"id":"1","nombre":"Prueba","precio":"25","denominacion":"DOC:
>   La Rioja"},   {"id_vino":"2","nombre":"Martinez la
>   cuesta","precio":"20","denominacion":"DOC: La Rioja"}]

Can somebody help me what i put wrong?

Regards
Roberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can find solution
problem was Webservice, If you use  jsonp: 'jsoncallback' need in WS return $_GET['jsoncallback'] how JSON object, if not put it, don't find any object and do error.

For example:

> echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 $(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function(){    
            var url2 = 'http://www.domain.com/',
            mode2 = 'ws.php?TIPO=',
            key2='OK';
    function logicaCliente(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
        var stuff = {"id":"2","nombre":"Martinez la cuesta","precio":"20","denominacion":"DOC: La Rioja"};
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(stuff);
        $.ajax({
            url: url2+mode2+key2 ,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            async: true,
             data: jsonString,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                $.each(result, function(i, row) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
                $('#data-list').append('<li><a href="" data-id="' + row.id + '"><h3>' + row.nombre + '</h3><p>' + row.denominacion + '</p></a></li>');
                 });
            $('#data-list').listview('refresh');
            },
            error: alert('Error en respuesta'),
            jsonpCallback: 'logicaCliente'
        });         
    });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

putting `error:function (a,b,c){ console.log(a,b,c); alert('Error en respuesta')},`

would show you the error :

> Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function,
>   getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function,
>   overrideMimeType: function…}  "parsererror" Error {stack: (...),
>   message: "logicaCliente was not called"}

`logicaCliente was not called` : This is from jQuery.

The callback is need to be execute but it has to be type of `application/javascript` **and it's not**

look :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 16 Mar 2014 12:50:56 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json <-----------
```

your response is not `jsonp` but `json` : `"Content-Type:application/json"`

Also , CORS headers are **not** present. so i dont see how this can work. ( in ie7 it would ( via `<script>` cuz of the array proto hack - but that's another unrelated story)

are you sure you're calling the right api ?

## edit

ofcourse it wont work. I run it from `jsfiddle.com` - your fiddle is useless. ( to our testings :-)

please add this `error:function (a,b,c){ alert(a+'   '+b+'   '+c);`

and tell us what is the result.

## also :

move

```
function logicaCliente(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
```

to the GLOBAL SCOPE> not inside of the function

Comment: Where i must put logicaCliente, i try out ajax function, out $(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function(), but same error. When i received that a i need update list view, if jsonpCallback is executed when i received answer, in this where i have to put code update list view and not in success??

Answer (score 0):

I have done one fixe between two answer and i can see in consola show is executed jsonpCallback but after do error and not fill list view:

> Error: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js
>   is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one callback
>   successundefined Cadena vacía pasada a getElementById().
>
> ...tion(c){var
>   d=this._search;this._timer&&(b.clearTimeout(this._timer),this._timer...
>
> jquery....min.js (línea 8) parsererror; Error: undefined was not
>   called;[object Object] pagina.html (línea 52)

Code fixed is:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function(){      

        var stuff = {
            id:null,
            nombre:null,
            precio:null,
            denominacion:null
            };
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(stuff);

 $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.dominio.com/ws.php?TIPO=OK" ,
        crossDomain: true,
        type:"GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
            async: true,
            data: jsonString,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                $.each(result, function(i, row) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
                $('#data-list').append('<li><a href="" data-id="' + row.id + '"><h3>' + row.nombre + '</h3><p>' + row.denominacion + '</p></a></li>');
                 });
            $('#data-list').listview('refresh');
            },
            error:  function(xhr, status, error){
                        console.log(status + '; ' + error+ ';');},
            jsonpCallback:function(response) {
                        console.log('callback success'+response);
            }
        });         
    });
```

In webserver is very simple only do a select and encapsule in JSON , i try with Content-type: application/javascript" and "Content-type: application/json" but same result,this is web service code

```
<?php
include($DIRCONF . 'conf/VARIABLES.ini.php'); //incluimos configuración
include($DIRCONF . 'JSON.php');
$tipo=$_GET['TIPO'];
$json = new Services_JSON;

$conexion = mysql_connect(SERVIDOR_MYSQL, USUARIO_MYSQL, PASSWORD_MYSQL);
mysql_select_db(BASE_DATOS, $conexion);

$que = "SELECT * FROM `DATOS`";

$res = mysql_query($que, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
 //Cerramos la conexion a la base de datos
 mysql_close($conexion);


//header("Content-type: application/javascript");
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data) ;
?>
```

Comment: [object object] i have read in other post is a problem with not exist field, but this error appear too comment $.each(result, function(i, row) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
                $('#vino-list').append('<li><a href="" data-id="' + row.id_vino + '"><h3>' + row.nombre + '</h3><p>' + row.denominacion + '</p></a></li>');
                 });

Comment: Somebody may help me? i continue in same point try it but i don't know follow